# How to find the volume under a 3D curve?

Tags: integration, 3d, curves, volume

So imagine I have a curved roof (imagine one side of a sine wave) with an arbitrary length. Now imagine there is a rectangular carpet underneath with its center aligned with the peak of the roof. I need to find the volume, from the base of the rectangle up to the roof (so a cuboid with a curved top).

Thereafter, I need to change the orientation of the rectangle (with the center still aligned) by 25 degrees in the x-direction and see how that changes the total volume.

The length of the wave in x-direction would be 8.5m with a height of 0.03m. The wave can be described as a sine/cos curve. The rectangle dimension is 0.4mx0.5m.

How would I go about this? I added a quick sketch.

[image: Need to find the volume of the red parts]

Comment: If you have a function $z=f(x,y)$, you can use the definite double integral $\iint f(x,y) dx dy$ with the appropriate bounds.

Comment: Welcome to MSE (again). <> _Please_ do not [post the same question twice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4233982/how-to-calculate-the-volume-under-3d-curve-based-on-specific-area-input).

Comment: @Patricio how would I go about doing that for these dimensions. Also what about when the rectangle is twisted by 25 degrees?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang the last question was closed due to the lack of clarity. I was asked to post again.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this a repost of the same question by the same author.

Comment: user244717 You were supposed to add clarity to the first version. See the edit button under it. Click it. Do a good enough job, and that version will be reopened.

Comment: @ Jyrki Lahtonen I will delete the other one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what double integration solves.  You have a $f(x,y) = A\sin\omega x + B$ that describes the height of the roof.   The limits of integration will describe the area of the carpet.

$\int_{-\frac L2}^{\frac L2}\int_{-\frac W2}^{\frac W2} A\cos\omega x + B\ dx\ dy$

Changing the orientation of the carpet changes the limits of integration.  Or, you can apply a change of variables that will re-orient your height function to your new variables.

$x = u\cos \phi + v\sin\phi\\
y = v\cos \phi - u\sin\phi$

($\phi$ is your rotation angle)

$\int_{-\frac L2}^{\frac L2}\int_{-\frac w2}^{\frac w2} A\cos(\omega u\cos\phi + \omega v\sin\phi) + B\ du\ dv$

If you don't like the change of variables, you can view the rotated region as a triangular region, a parallelogram, and a second triangle.

Comment: Interesting, this makes sense. For clarification, (1) would you say that since the centre of the rectangle should be aligned to the centre peak of the roof I could change the sine to cosine? (2) for the second equation would the all i have to input is the change in orientation and the limits at that orientation? (3) The roof is 8.5m long in the x direction, how does the above equation account for that? Thank you so much

Comment: It should be a cosine function to align the centerline of the carpet with the apex of the roof.  I will change that.

Comment: thank you! Just to confirm if I wish to account for the wavelength here, I would simply multiply (ωucosϕ+ωvsinϕ) by 2pi/wavelength before implementing this integral?

Comment: Choosing the correct value of $\omega$ accounts for the wavelength.